# Remove Iptables log from kern.log syslog messages

Tags: iptables, logging, rsyslog

I'm having trouble with Iptables logs, i'm not able to get them out from kern.log, syslog and message files.

I added two rules in rsyslog.conf which redirect my messages to an "iptables.log" file but logs are also present in kern logs.

Here is my rsyslog.conf :

```
###############
#### RULES ####
###############

# Iptables
:msg,contains,"IPT IN/DP: " -/var/log/iptables.log
:msg,contains,"IPT6 IN/DP: " -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~


#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none,cron.none                -/var/log/syslog
cron.*                          /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log

#(some other rules ....)
mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages
```

How can I do to log iptable dropped packet only in iptables.log and not in kern.log files?

Comment: Do you have an example iptables rule you can post?  You know that iptables can set the set the `--log-level` or a `--log-prefix` both of which you can use to filter messages to a specific log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where the `& ~` comes from, but at least the following should perform what you want:

```
# Iptables
:msg,contains,"IPT IN/DP: " -/var/log/iptables.log
:msg,contains,"IPT6 IN/DP: " -/var/log/iptables.log
:msg,contains,"IPT IN/DP: " ~
:msg,contains,"IPT6 IN/DP: " ~
```

Maybe not most elegant, but a similar config seems to work for me.

Comment: According to rsyslog man page the line "& ~" says to delete the previous message otherwise it would be logged in kern.log and other kernel logging files.

Comment: @AlbertoSpelta I don't spot anything mentioning `&` in the man page of rsyslog.conf in Debian  7.4... OTOH `*.* ~` is mentioned to discard everything.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an example iptables rule you can post?  You know that iptables can set the set the `--log-level` or a `--log-prefix` both of which you can use to filter messages to a specific log file.

By default iptables stuff is going to be directed to `kern.info`.  If you aren't using any options to set an alternate level you You can update your config for syslog to this.

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none;\
        kern.!info              -/var/log/syslog
```

You could do a similar thing for kern.log, but keep in mind that this will also redirect other kern.info messages, not just iptables.  So maybe something like this would meet your needs?  The kern_info.log will probably be 99.9% iptables logs.

```
 kern.*;kern.!info              -/var/log/kern.log
 kern.info                      -/var/log/kern_info.log
```

I have read that rsyslog has some pretty advanced filtering though.  So you could probably set a `--log-prefix` and do some advanced filtering with that instead of just using the service/severity for filtering.

Comment: My rule look like this (i have a second one in ipv6 table with the IPT6 IN/DP prefix) :
`LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "IPT IN/DP: "`
`DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0`